# Debian: how to install a 64 bit package using apt?

Tags: debian, apt, 64-bit

I am migrating my system to 64 bit and the debian wiki suggests to first debootstrap a 64bit into a directory, then collect all 64bit packages and install them but this doesn't work.

To install 64bit of a package they suggest to use package-name:amd64

"Upgrade your 32-bit system closest to the mini system
In order to have your 32-bit system as much as compatible (from the configuration files POV) to your mini 64-bit system, upgrade all your packages you have installed in the 64-bit mini root."

but for instance
apt-get install zlib1g:amd64 gives

E: Unable to locate package zlib1g

None of the package:arch works at all.

How do I install the amd64 port of a package?

Edit: It seems https://wiki.debian.org/Migrate32To64Bit is outdated and the procedure has changed.

Comment: You can't use 64 bit executables on a 32 bit kernel. You'd have to boot from a 64 bit kernel to have a chance of it working. I don't know if you can install a 64 bit kernel deb from a 32 bit kernel. Otherwise you'd have to just put 64 bit kernel and initrd with all required modules in a place where GRUB can get to them, and then start the 64 bit kernel manually from the command line. But other tricks are needed as well, because the 64 bit kernel won't help locate 64 bit packages.

Comment: What guide are you trying to follow Jherek?  What release are you currently running?  Are you on wheezy?  Or testing/unstable?  Did you read the first bolded statement in the guide?  https://wiki.debian.org/Migrate32To64Bit  **These instructions do not work on current Debian stable with Multiarch**.  Stable = Wheezy.

Comment: @kasperd, installing a 64 bit kernel on a 32 bit system via multi-arch is actually pretty easy, and is supported.  Upgrading the rest of the system to 64 bit is far more difficult.

Comment: BTW, I strongly suggest that you give up on this, and consider backing up your data, and re-installing with 64 bit media.  It will almost certainly be easier to simply re-install.

Comment: @kasperd: I installed 64bit kernel, it's easy, you just need to install the apt-package and the deb for the kernel and that was it. It even boots and the kernel is backward compatible, so it can run most 32bit programs. But in order to keep the system consistency I should update the other packages too.

Comment: @Zoredace: Yes that's the guide I was following. I stuck at updating my 64bit packages. Where can I find further informations?